# I can't add commands to my discord bot with discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots, discord, discord.py

Here's my code:

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord
import config

class Bot(commands.AutoShardedBot):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(command_prefix="~")

    @commands.command()
    async def test(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send("some random text")

    def run(self):
        super().run(config.TOKEN)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot = Bot()
    bot.run()
```

So now, when I type `~test`, it should respond with `some random text`, but instead, this error message pops up in the terminal:

```
Ignoring exception in command None:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "test" is not found
```

I don't see what I did wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Discord.py currently couldn't automatically register the commands from subclasses of `Client` that are decorated by `@commands.command()`. You can still however, manually add them in `__init__` or anywhere that's going to be ran:

```
class Bot(commands.AutoShardedBot):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(command_prefix="~")
        self.add_command(commands.Command("test", self.test))
        # or uglier:
        self.command()(self.test)

    async def test(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send("some random text")
```

You can still use the decorator if you wanted to (I'd prefer this way since it's more simplistic):

```
class Bot(commands.AutoShardedBot):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(command_prefix="~")
        self.add_command(self.test)

    @commands.command()
    async def test(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send("some random text")
```

---

If you're going to have lots of initial commands and lazy to call `add_command` for each of them, you can do the following:

```
import inspect

class Bot(commands.AutoShardedBot):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(command_prefix="~")

        members = inspect.getmembers(self)
        for name, member in members:
            if isinstance(member, commands.Command):
                if member.parent is None:
                    self.add_command(member)

    @commands.command()
    async def test(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send("some random text")

    @commands.command()
    async def test2(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send("some random text2")

    @commands.command()
    async def test3(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send("some random text3")
```

Comment: there may be a change in api since this answer as `Command.__init__` now use only one parametter : func, and kwargs.
so in the first exemple would be `self.add_command(commands.Command(self.test, name="test"))`  instead of `self.add_command(commands.Command("test", self.test))`

Answer (score 0):

Try to do:

**main.py**

```
import discord
import os

client = discord.Client

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
if message.content.startswith("!hello")
await message.channel.send("hello!")

client.run(os.getenv("TOKEN"))
```

**.env**

```
TOKEN=paste your token here
```